# Confusion for the solution of the heat equation in a one dimensional bar

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

The heat equation for a one dimensional bar is given by
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u = k \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u$$
where $k$ is the diffusion coefficient, and the boundary conditions are given by 
$$u(0,t) = u(L, t) = 0\ \forall t \geq 0$$
where $L$ is the length of the bar. Moreover at time $t = 0$, the temperature is given by a known function $f(x)$, i.e.,
$$u(x, 0) = f(x)\ \forall x \in [0, L].$$

Assuming that $u(x, t) = X(x) \cdot T(t)$, we can reduce the heat equation to the following system
$$\begin{cases}X''(x) + \lambda^2 X(x) &= &0,\\ T'(t) + \lambda^2 k T(t) &= &0. \end{cases}$$
Both equations can be solved, and we have
$$X(x) = A_{+} e^{i \lambda x} + A_{-}e^{-i\lambda x}$$
for the first one, and 
$$T(t) = B e^{-\lambda^2 k t}$$
for the second one. Thus we get
$$u(x, t) = (C_1 e^{i \lambda x} + C_2 e^{-i\lambda x})e^{-\lambda^2 k t}.$$
Assuming $C_1 = -C_2$ and since $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $\sin(\lambda L) = 0 \iff \lambda = \frac{m \pi}{L}$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, we finally get 
$$u(x, t) = C_1 2 i \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) e^{-\frac{m^2 \pi^2 kt}{L^2}}.$$
Letting $b_m := C_1 2 i$, the general solution is given by
$$u(x, t) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) e^{-\frac{m^2 \pi^2 kt}{L^2}}.$$
Because of the boundary condition $u(x, 0) = f(x)$, we also have
$$u(x, 0) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) = f(x)$$
which is a Fourier serie in sine of period $2L$ and where $b_m$ is a constant.

---

Sorry for the long introduction, this is taken from a class I followed, and I have a few questions about it.

1. Since $b_m$ is constant, do we not have 
   $$u(x, 0) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) - \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) = 0?$$
2. I thought that the bar was heated at a certain $x$ until time $t=0$, and then one would just observe how the heat was diffusing. To simplify the question, assume $L = \pi$, $k = 1$ and $C_1 2 i = 1$, so that the solution is 
   $$u(x, t) = \sin\left( mx \right) e^{-m^2 t}.$$
   Plugging $m = 2$ above leads to 
   $$u(x, 0) = \sin\left(2x\right),$$
   meaning that some parts of the bar have a negative temperature. Am I understanding this correctly, or do I make a mistake? Because this is super weird to me that after being heated, some parts of the bar can have subzero temperature.
3. What happens if we assume that $u(0,t) = u(L,t) \neq 0$?
4. What happens if we assume that $u(0, t) \neq u(L, t)$?
5. Can someone provide intuition on what $X(x)$ and $T(t)$ represent in the variable separation?

---

Comment: 1. The $b_m$ are not constant inside the sum. In particular, you cannot assume $b_m=b_{-m}.$ Moreover, you seem to have left out $b_0$ in your sum.

Comment: 2. What happened to all the other terms in the sum?

Comment: 3. You have to use a different solution method, because the BC's are no longer homogeneous. Generally, you use some sort of transformation to get a new independent variable, say, $v(x,t)$ that satisfies a similar PDE but with homogeneous BC's. You'd probably do a similar sort of thing with 4.

Comment: 5. The $X(x)$ and $T(t)$ represent single-variable portions of the solution. That's all. They are helper variables *introduced along the way*, and hence have no final meaning in and of themselves.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I left out $b_0$ because $\sin(0) = 0$. Since I can't assume $b_m = b_{-m}$, how do I know their values? Can I choose them, or do they depend on the initial conditions? For 2., I used just the particular solution $u(x, t) = C_1 2 i \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) e^{-\frac{m^2 \pi^2 kt}{L^2}}.$. I'm not sure I can do that, but I was trying to plot what the solutions looked like, and it may be one of the reasons I'm confused.

Comment: You choose the $b_m$ to match your initial conditions via Fourier analysis.@JJacquelin has a very good answer there.

Comment: Hell I didn't realize until now that $f(x) $ is provided and this is what will determine the coefficients... Sorry guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposal 1. : Since $b_m$ is constant, do we not have 
$$u(x, 0) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) - \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) = 0?$$

NO. Don't confuse ($b_m$ in $m>0$) and ($b_m$ in $m<0$). 
$$u(x, 0) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} b_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right) + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} b_{-m} \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right)$$
With $B_m=b_m+b_{-m}$ , better use this form of Fourier series : 
$$u(x, 0) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} B_m \sin\left( \frac{m \pi x}{L} \right)$$

Proposal 2. : I thought that the bar was heated at a certain $x$ until time $t=0$, and then one would just observe how the heat was diffusing. To simplify the question, assume $L = \pi$, $k = 1$ and $C_1 2 i = 1$, so that the solution is 
$$u(x, t) = \sin\left( mx \right) e^{-m^2 t}.$$

NO. One cannot separate one term of the series. The Fourrier series a whole :
$$u(x, t) =\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} B_m \sin\left( mx \right) e^{-m^2 t}.$$
Some $B_m$ can be positive and others negative, depending on the function $f(x)$ on a given range $0<x<L$. 
Of course, at various $t$ some terms are negative but the sum will be such as $u$ remains positive on this limited range insofar $f(x)$ is positive on this range.

Outside the range where the Fourrier series is considered and where the coefficients are computed, the Fourier series is not valide and the computed $u(x,t)$ has no signifiance (so, doesn't mind if it becomes negative).

Comment: Negativity doesn't really matter anyway, it just means that your system of units has negative temperature (like Celsius does). Thankfully we have the maximum principle to tell us that if all the temperatures initially in our problem (between the initial and boundary conditions) are nonnegative then our temperatures in the solution will also be nonnegative.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is stupid, but why can't $u(x,t) = \sin(mt)\exp(-m^2 t)$ be a solution instead of taking the whole Fourier serie? We have $u_t(x,t) = -m^2 \sin(mx) \exp(-m^2 t) = u_{xx}(x,t)$ and it satisfies the boundary conditions, right?

Comment: @LaurentHayez $u(x,t)=\sin(m \pi x/L)\exp(-(m\pi/L)^2 t)$ works if the initial condition was $\sin(m\pi x/L)$. You need the series to satisfy an arbitrary initial condition.

Comment: Yes, it took me way too long to realize that $f(x) $ is provided and that the coefficients in the serie are determined from this... Feels bad man.